# Problems writing a query to match records between tables with complex matching criteria

Tags: sql-server-2008, join, matching

I have a matching algorithm that I need to build on a large dataset in a SQL Server 2008 database.  This is a minimal example of the kind of thing I need.

Say I have table1 and table2 each with just four columns, unique_id, col1, col2 and col3.

```
CREATE TABLE table1 
(
    unique_id VARCHAR(4),
    col1 INT,
    col2 INT,
    col3 INT
);

INSERT INTO table1 
VALUES ('ADAF', '2', '4', '17'),
       ('WSDA', '1', null, '12');
GO

CREATE TABLE table2 
(
    unique_id VARCHAR(4),
    col1 INT,
    col2 INT,
    col3 INT
);

INSERT INTO table2 
VALUES ('QWAS', '2', '4', '17'),
       ('FDFR', '3', '4', '17'),
       ('LKPY', '2', '4', null),
       ('FGDA', '1', null, '12'),
       ('GAPU', '1', '3', '12');
```

For all the records in table1, I want to return the unique IDs in table1 and the unique_ids in table2 where at least two out of three of the variables in col1, col2 and col3 are the same.  It is OK if one of the variables does not match because it contains a null, but if any of the three columns contain a non-null value that does not match its counterpart in the other table then the match is automatically invalidated.

So in this example in table1 record ID ADAF will return QWAS (exact match) and LKPY as the non-null values match, but not FDFR because there is a non-match in col1.
WSDA will return FGDA and also GAPU as the null to 3 does not count as a mismatch.

I can solve this (inefficiently) by using a union query to get matches on the three columns into a temp table then linking this back to the original data with joins using another union query to get any invalidated matches, then running a query returning all matches, net of any invalidated matches.

However, my real world application needs me to match 3 out of 6 variables, with approximately 10 million rows in my record set matching to a much larger set of possible matches, so I need something more efficient.

Comment: Just as a note: SQL Server 2008 and 2008 R2 are **out of extended support** by now - https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/database-administration/the-end-of-sql-server-2008-and-2008-r2-extended-support/ - time to upgrade!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the results you want by JOINing the tables on matching values on each column while also allowing for `NULL` values to act as a match, and then counting the number of actual matches and requiring that to be at least 2:

```
SELECT t1.unique_id AS t1_id, t2.unique_id AS t2_id
FROM table1 t1
JOIN table2 t2 ON (t1.col1 = t2.col1 OR t1.col1 IS NULL OR t2.col1 IS NULL)
              AND (t1.col2 = t2.col2 OR t1.col2 IS NULL OR t2.col2 IS NULL)
              AND (t1.col3 = t2.col3 OR t1.col3 IS NULL OR t2.col3 IS NULL)
              AND CASE WHEN t1.col1 = t2.col1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
                + CASE WHEN t1.col2 = t2.col2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
                + CASE WHEN t1.col3 = t2.col3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
                >= 2
```

Output (for your sample data)

```
t1_id   t2_id
ADAF    QWAS
ADAF    LKPY
WSDA    FGDA
WSDA    GAPU
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2012&fiddle=b94f521702714ed01cd3212d86f56318)

Comment: Thank you this solution is just what I need.